# Error in Create Table Syntax MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, create-table

This is my create table syntax:

```
Create table Recipe(
    Recipename varchar(30), 
    Cuisine varchar(20), 
    Skilllevel varchar(13), 
    Ingredients varchar(400), 
    Procedure varchar(1000), 
    Cookingtime int(30), 
    Category varchar(10), 
    Restrictions varchar(15)
);
```

I'm not able to identify the error in this. Please do help. Thanks

Comment: `Procedure` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html). Need another name or surround it with backticks.

Comment: Sit down with any basic introductory book or tutorial. This is a long way from a sensible design. And what the hell is int(30)?

Answer (score 1):

INT doesn't need a (30) value + you cant use word Procedure. Changed it to Procedures

```
 Create table Recipe(
         Recipename varchar(30), 
         Cuisine varchar(20), 
         Skilllevel varchar(13), 
         Ingredients varchar(400), 
         Procedures varchar(1000), 
         Cookingtime int, 
         Category varchar(10), 
         Restrictions varchar(15));
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

`Procedure` is a [reserved word](http://Procedure%20is%20a%20reserved%20word.%20Need%20another%20name%20or%20surround%20it%20with%20backticks.). Need another name or surround it with backticks.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Isaiah answered your question but I wanted to add: depending on what kind of format you want the Cookingtime to be in, you could use the time datatype for long cook times (several hours) or keep using int if you are using minutes.